# having errors installing appcompt in Xamarin studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

errors installing appcompt in Xamarin studio:

> Package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.24.2.1' does not exist in project 'ServerLandNews'
>   Package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.24.2.1' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\PRINCESO\Documents\Projects\ServerLandNews\packages'
>   Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 24.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` to 7.0 or greater. See the `Dependencies` section of NuGet which demonstrates this:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat/24.2.1

Target Framework Documentation:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/#framework

Comment: FYI: There are no `Dependencies` that show up on the `24.2.x` packages on the nuget website (i.e. `This package has no dependencies.`), it depends upon the package, some show up only with the download package, others include the MonoDroid version, etc....

Comment: This is because this package is over a year old and didn't have a dependency on the `Support.Annotations` package which threw all of those nasty warnings about enums. Otherwise, download the `nupkg` and use `NuGet Package Explorer` or extract it and look at the `lib` folder for the proper framework needed. Feel free to comment on the following to make it easier: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4051